# Make css inline from specific stylesheet not from every part of the code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need a way to get certain CSS attributes for all HTML elements in a page and make them inline. I have a  with custom CSS attributes, for example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    h2 { color: red; }
</style>
```

And then:

```
<h2>This is my title</h2>
```

So, I need a script that will make the following change (and only the following):

```
<h2 style="color: red;">This is my title</h2>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Use class h2.special{color:red;}

Comment: If it's a one off thing use [Mailchimp CSS Inliner](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css) or you can integrate with the `API` (API docs [here](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/helper/inline-css.php)) for dynamic code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basics of CSS:

This will make all h2 tags have a text color of red

```
<style type="text/css">
    h2 { color: red; }
</style>

<h2>I'm red</h2>
<h2>I'm also red</h2>
<h1>I'm not red</h1>
```

This will make all tags with the class of chicken be red.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .chicken { color: red; } /* chicken is the class name*/
</style>

<h2 class = "chicken">I'm red</h2>
<div class = "chicken">I'm also red</div>
<h2>I'm not red</h2>
```

If you only want to give one tag a specific property you give it an id

```
<style type="text/css">
    #chicken { color: red; }
</style>

<h2 id= "chicken">I'm red</h2>
```

I don't really understand what you're looking form, but the property for making something inline is:

```
display:inline
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

If you replace the color:red with display:inline then their properties will change from being red to inline.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "get certain CSS attributes for all HTML elements in a page and make them inline." What are you trying to do?

For individual inline styling, use the span tag:

```
My mummy has <span style="color:blue">blue</span> eyes.
```

To style certain elements, as the user above has done with jQuery, use a class tag for each element that you wish to style:

CSS:
    .specialStyle {color: #00d;}

HTML:

```
<div id="anyOldDiv" class="specialStyle">...</div> 
<a href="someAddress.html" class="specialStyle">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to do it for h2 elements and for CSS color attribute then the following should work

```
$('h2').each(function(){
   $(this).css('color', $(this).css('color'));
});
```

If you want other elements/attributes then you will need to build it out.